# Why isn't "NOT ( <search_condition> )" listed in definition?

Tags: t-sql

Based on testing, `WHERE NOT` is valid SQL syntax

```
 where  not ( x = 10  y > 5 )
```

However, I don't follow that from the definition:

To me, the T-SQL definition of a search condition doesn't seem to allow producing `NOT ( <search_condition> )`"

The spec/docs makes it seem like the only legitimate target for a unary negation is a predicate. To produce `not ( <search_condition> )` it looks like this requires the statement to be the right hand side of a conjunction or disjunction...Is the spec incorrect, or am I missing a way to produce this?

```
< search_condition > ::= 
    { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } 
    [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } ] 
[ ,...n ] 
<predicate> ::= 
    { expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } expression 
    | string_expression [ NOT ] LIKE string_expression 
  [ ESCAPE 'escape_character' ] 
    | expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN expression AND expression 
    | expression IS [ NOT ] NULL 
    | CONTAINS 
  ( { column | * } ,'< contains_search_condition >') 
    | FREETEXT ( { column | * } ,'freetext_string') 
    | expression [ NOT ] IN (subquery | expression [ ,...n ] ) 
    | expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } 
  { ALL | SOME | ANY} (subquery) 
    | EXISTS (subquery)     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT` is listed in square brackets in both parts, meaning it's optional.

If we expand this:

```
< search_condition > ::= 
    { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } 
    [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } ] 
[ ,...n ]
```

, removing some of the square brackets and possibly their contents, we get this:

```
< some_search_condition > ::= { NOT ( <search_condition> ) }
```

which your string matches.

Comment: But the first part isn't optional: a search condition will always produce either: `[NOT] <predicate>` **or** `( <search_condition> )` and *then* it will add stuff on in the second optional part where producing `NOT ( <search_condition> )` is pretty easy...

Comment: Can you break down how you remove the brackets for me?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: in a grammar, you can remove square brackets either with or without their contents, meaning you either leave or remove the optional part. Now, I first removed brackets around `NOT` then removed the second pair with all their content.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: alternation symbol applies to variables left and right to it. If the syntax were to describe `[NOT] <predicate>` *or* `( <search_condition> )`, the former would have to make a group: `{ { [NOT] predicate} | ( <search_condition> ) }`

Comment: Had to read that 50* to get it. I feel dumb now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

[Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)

> [ ] (brackets) Optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets.

That syntax link is on the page with the definition
[Search Condition (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx)

> Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions

What do you mean it does not support not?
Post a query that fails.

This runs just fine

```
 select nativeMD5
   from docSVsys 
   join docSVtext 
     on docSVtext.fieldID = 110 
    and docSVtext.sID = docSVsys.sID
  where not (docSVsys.sID = 10 or docSVsys.sID = 11)
```

Comment: I'm not saying it fails. I'm saying I don't understand the railroad diagrams.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @Blam: Christopher asks how to read a syntax diagram, not how to write a query.